# Azure Storage FindBlobsByTag possibility of ordering and taking n results

Tags: c#, azure, tags, azure-blob-storage

I've recently started using Azure Storage's `FindBlobsByTagAsync`, and I wonder if there's a way in which I can:

1. take *n* results
2. order the results so that I get the first or last *n* results

I'm using the following code to retrieve a subset of blobs by tag...

```
private async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<string>> GetBlobNamesByTagAsync(BlobContainerClient sourceContainer, int take)
{
    var taken = 0;
    var blobNames = new List<string>();

    await foreach (var taggedBlob in sourceContainer.FindBlobsByTagsAsync(...))
    {
        blobNames.Add(taggedBlob.BlobName);
        taken++;

        if (taken == take)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return blobNames;
}
```

... but does the blob-tagging API permit me to specify a *take* amount, or to specify that I want the (lexigraphically) first or last *n* blobs?

Comment: Just FYI - blob storage doesn't have any type of database engine associated with it - you only have blob names + metadata, and you can enumerate these, but that's pretty much it (ok you can filter, but that still requires 100% enumeration). Even folder names aren't really filterable (they're just an extension of the filename, unless you're using ADLS). You can do all of your filtering/sorting client-side, or store all metadata in a database, where you can index/sort/search/etc on any property.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon. I knew that already but the tags must be somehow abstracted from the blobs to which they correspond - they're indexed, after all.  I suppose what I'm asking is "Can the tags - not the blobs _per se_ - be ordered and then take _n_"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, There is no direct class to achieve this. However, I tried sorting the tags, selecting the n tags and its respective blobs using the below code.

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var taken = 0;
        var blobNames = new List<string>();
        var TagNames = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        BlobContainerClient sourceContainer = new BlobContainerClient("<Connection String >", "container");


        foreach (var blob in sourceContainer.GetBlobs())
        {
            string blobName = blob.Name;
            BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient($"<Connection String>", "container",blobName);
            var tags = blobClient.GetTags().Value.Tags;
            foreach (var tag in tags)
            {
                TagNames[tag.Key] = tag.Value;
            }
        }


        var sortedTag = TagNames.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the n value");
        string number = Console.ReadLine();
        int n = int.Parse(number);
        int ind = 0;
        
        foreach (var item in sortedTag)
        {
            if(ind<n)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                ind++;
                foreach (var taggedBlob in sourceContainer.FindBlobsByTags($"{item.Key}='{item.Value}'"))
                {
                    blobNames.Add(taggedBlob.BlobName);
                    Console.WriteLine(taggedBlob.BlobName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]